# How does a probability graph of f=math.random()*math.random() looks like

Tags: static

We have a function:

f=math.random()*math.random()

obviouse, on average this should give 0.25, since we take a random number between 0 and 1 twice. But how does a plot of this graph looks like? What's the odd of getting 0.2, what is the odd of getting 0.8 (+/-0.05 or something)?

I tried to convince wolframalpha to make a plot for me, or anydice, but i can't figure out how to make that work. How could I make a probability graph for questions like this?

Comment: A good place to start would be learning about binomial distributions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution as well as normal distributions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformProductDistribution.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Hobbs, this This is [Uniform Product Distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformProductDistribution.html). It looks like this:

[image: Uniform Product Distribution]

n=2 (red), n=3 (yellow), and so on.